# "base_geoengine" module installation error in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I am trying to install `base_geoengine` module in `odoo 10` on `windows` but it is giving me below error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init_postgis'
```

can anyone please tell me how can i solve it.

Comment: Can you create new database and just install this one module? Will it show you the same error?

Comment: I had already tried... I  am working with windows.. please keep in mind..

Answer (score 0):

I executed the following lines manually in postgresql:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

After I commented out the following line in **manifest.py** of base_geoengine:

```
'pre_init_hook': 'init_postgis',
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might occur because you ware using `base_geoengine` module of version 11. Clone version 10 from OCA community, it might solve your problem.